# StackExchange.Redis, cannot recover from server failure and recovery

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I run a test app which connects to the Redis server in the following way:

```
var options = new ConfigurationOptions();
options.AbortOnConnectFail = false;
options.EndPoints.Add(Settings.HostName + ":" + Settings.Port);

Connection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(options);
Connection.ConnectionFailed += (sender, args) => SystemMessageCallback(new SystemMessage(SystemMessageType.Error, "Connection to Redis Server failed: " + args.Exception.Message));
Connection.ConnectionRestored += (sender, args) => SystemMessageCallback(new SystemMessage(SystemMessageType.Error, "Connection to Redis Server restored: " + args.Exception.Message));

if (!IsConnected())
{
    SystemMessageCallback(new SystemMessage(SystemMessageType.Error, "Connection to Redis Server failed"));
}
```

When I now shut down the server (while my client is still running) I am getting the following error message:

> Connection to Redis Server failed: SocketFailure on
>   127.0.0.1:6379/Interactive, input-buffer: 0, outstanding: 0, last-read: 9s ago, last-write: 9s ago, keep-alive: -1s, pending: 0,
>   state: ConnectedEstablished, last-heartbeat: 0s ago, last-mbeat: 0s
>   ago, global: 0s ago

All goes as expected (I cannot comment on the exact error message content above as it originates from within StackExchange.Redis) but when I re-start the server the client does not recover from the server shutdown anymore, the callback is not invoked on `Connection.ConnectionRestored`. Is there anything that I am doing incorrectly?

My C# client is StackExchange.Redis version 1.0.242.0 (v4.0.30319) and I run version 2.8.4 of the MS Open Tech Group, though I suspect the error originates from StackExchange.Redis.

Comment: that should just work. I will have to investigate

Comment: thanks for taking a look.

Comment: @MarcGravell, just wondering did you have a chance to check out this issue? Thanks a lot

Comment: @MarcGravell, has this issue somehow been fixed? I updated to the newest version (via Nuget) and still the ConnectionRestored event never triggers. I get an error message (via the ConnectionFailed event) when I forcefully shut down the Redis Server instance but restarting it will not restore the connection in my client app (both server and client sit on the same local machine). Thanks